# Fetch Last 24 hour data using Gemfire OQL

Tags: java, spring-data-gemfire, oql

Can anyone help me with fecthing exactly last 24 hr data directly using gemfire OQL or some custom java code.

i tried using LIKE query and fetch two days of data but i am not sure how two pass dynamic data in gemfire query since everything is treated as string.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you require data for a specific time frame, you will have to add a field which will the contain the date/data you want to query against.

In your case you want to query some time parameter. Best way to store this, would be a `long` field that would represent the Date as a long. Then your query would require a simple `>=` and `<` comparison, which are quick, because they aren't String comparisons.

`String query = "SELECT * from /DataRegion r where r.createdDate >= $1 AND r.createdDate < $2";`

Then your query becomes simpler, as all you'd have to do is determine the start and end date in terms of its `long` representation. `new Date(2023,03,10).getTime()` (of course you should use the java.util.Calender class, but this is just for example purposes).

Then using the bind logic in GemFire, you can then run the query.

```
Query query = queryService.newQuery(queryString);

// set a query bind parameter
Object[] params = new Object[2];
params[0] = new Date(2023,03,10).getTime();
params[1] = new Date(2023,03,12).getTime();

// Execute the query locally. It returns the results set.
SelectResults results = (SelectResults) query.execute(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Udo is correct, here!

Storing or exposing some timestamp (`long` or `Long' value) on your application domain object(s), that are stored and managed in VMware GemFire, is actually preferable in this case.

It could even look something like this...

```java
package example.app.customers.model;

import java.time.Instant
...
@Region("Customers")
class Customer {

  private Long id;

  private Instant joined;

  private final String name;

  public long getJoinedTimestamp() {

    Instant localJoined = this.joined;

    return localJoined != null ? localJoined.toEpochMilli() : 0L;
  }

  // other getters, setters and accessors omitted

}
```

However, I would NOT use `java.util.Calendar`, but rather use the (`@since`) **Java 8** date/time types in the `java.time` package ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html)), like `java.time.Instant` ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html)).

Then, it would also be a simple matter to write a derived query using the ***Spring Data (SD) [GemFire]*** *Repository* abstraction, too!

There is no need to use GemFire's OQL-based query API (:P) in this case!

So, you could have SD GemFire Repository declaration like the following:

```java
package example.app.customers.repo;

interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

  List<Customer> findByJoinedTimestampGreaterThanEqualAndJoinedTimestampLessThan(Long begin, Long end);
```

> NOTE: The time range could be inclusive, too, such as `findByJoinedTimestampGreaterThanEqualAndJoinedTimestampLessThanEqual(..)` as well.

> NOTE: In my example above, the joined timestamp is inclusive on the lower bound and exclusive on the upper bound.

You can find out more about *Spring Data GemFire's* (SDG) extension of *Spring Data's (SD) Repository* infrastructure and querying capabilities here, in the [SDG doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories), and specifically on SDG derived (OQL) queries in [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories.queries.executing) as well.

For more general information on the *Spring Data Repository* infrastructure abstraction, see the *Spring Data Commons'* [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories), and specifically about [query methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the query docs: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-GemFire/10.0/gf/getting_started-querying_quick_reference.html

Here's an example of how to use bind parameters.

```
// specify the  query string
 String queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM /exampleRegion p WHERE p.status = $1";

QueryService queryService = cache.getQueryService();
Query query = queryService.newQuery(queryString);

// set a query bind parameter
Object[] params = new Object[1];
params[0] = "active";

// Execute the query locally. It returns the results set.
SelectResults results = (SelectResults) query.execute(params);
```